# bootstrap-vue how to include b-form-datepicker in b-dropdown

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I'm building a dropdown menu date chooser, and want to allow the user to input a range of dates or have the option to choose a predetermined date range.

Is there a way to include the b-form-datepicker within a b-dropdown? When I try to open the datepicker, the dropdown closes. I've tried preventing the default closing action, but in doing so, I can't use the datepicker. Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated!

Below is a simple example, showing what I want to do.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      startDate: null,
      endDate: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    registerThisClick() {
      console.log("this is clicked")
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.6.2/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.21.2/dist/bootstrap-vue.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-dropdown id="dropdown-divider" text="Dropdown with divider" menu-class="w-100" class="w-100" >
    <template v-slot:default>
      <b-dropdown-item>3 months</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-dropdown-item>6 months</b-dropdown-item>
      <b-row>
        <b-col cols="12" class="my-2" >
        Start
            <b-form-datepicker
                id="datepicker-dateformat1"
                :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
                locale="en"
                v-model="startDate"
                @click="registerThisClick"
             ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-col>
        <b-col>
        End
            <b-form-datepicker
                id="datepicker-dateformat2"
                :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
                locale="en"
                v-model="endDate"
                @click="registerThisClick"
             ></b-form-datepicker>
        </b-col>
      </b-row>

    </template>
  </b-dropdown>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `@hide` on your dropdown to disable normal click/close and create a new button to trigger closing the dropdown.

Given that there is not a lot of support for this out of the box, you mightw want to consider using a modal or some other BV component.

[image]
**Template:**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div> {{ startDate }} </div>
    <div> {{ endDate }} </div>
    <div> {{ isCloseable }} </div>
    <b-dropdown id="dropdown-divider" ref='dropdown' text="Dropdown with divider" menu-class="w-100" class="w-100" @hide='handleHide($event)' @hidden='isCloseable=false'>
      <template v-slot:default>
        <b-dropdown-item>3 months</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-dropdown-item>6 months</b-dropdown-item>
        <b-row>
          <b-col cols="12" class="my-2" >
          Start
              <b-form-datepicker
                  id="datepicker-dateformat1"
                  ref="date1"
                  :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
                  locale="en"
                  v-model="startDate"
               ></b-form-datepicker>
          </b-col>
          <b-col>
          End
              <b-form-datepicker
                  id="datepicker-dateformat2"
                  :date-format-options="{ year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric' }"
                  locale="en"
                  v-model="endDate"
               ></b-form-datepicker>
          </b-col>
        </b-row>
        <b-dropdown-item @click='closeMe()'>Close me</b-dropdown-item>

      </template>
    </b-dropdown>
  </div>

</template>
```

**Script:**

```
<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';


@Component({
  components: {

  },
})

export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  startDate = null
  endDate = null
  isCloseable = false;

  handleHide(bvEvent) {
    if (!this.isCloseable) {
      bvEvent.preventDefault();  
    } else {
      this.$refs.dropdown.hide();
    }
  }

  closeMe() {
    this.isCloseable = true;
    this.$refs.dropdown.hide();
  }

}
</script>
```